# How to set rule using regex in scrapy for extracting urls?

Tags: regex, scrapy

I want to crawl pages related to Disney on bloomberg websites. The url follow pattern as

```
        "http://bloomberg.com/news/2013-07-08/disney-welcometohomepageofdisney"
```

So, i have written below rule for it

```
          rules = [
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/news/*/disney*',)), follow=True),
          ]
```

but the above rule doesn't working as i want and i am getting crawled pages output not related to Disney. please help to fix this rule.

Comment: it appears from my research that * isn't anything you still would need .* like normal regex, let me know if i'm wrong i'd be happy to change my regex for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/news/*` matches `/news` followed by any number of `/`.

The correct regex would be:

```
/news/.*/disney
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely need the following regex:

```
 /news/[^/]+/disney.*
```

which escaped looks like

```
\/news\/[^\/]+\/disney.*
```

this way you will find the next / but not anything.

[Example here](http://www.regex101.com/r/wA4vW9)